# kafka connect error Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0 due to node -1

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have configured Kafka connect for a sink connector. I am used a oracle managed service for producing message stream and want to write that to autonomous database.

following is worker properties:

```
group.id=test
bootstrap.servers=xxx.oci.oraclecloud.com:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
plugin.path=/opt/jdbc/connector/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.5.2
config.storage.topic=xxxx.osd7kemq-config
offset.storage.topic=xxxx.osd7kemq-offset
status.storage.topic=xxxx.osd7kemq-status
```

following is the connector config:

```
name=sink-test
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector

tasks.max=3
topics=teststream
"connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@pxxxhigh?TNS_ADMIN=/opt/jdbc/wallet"
"connection.user": "abc"
"connection.password": "Randompassword"
```

when I start the worker using

```
./bin/connect-distributed.sh ./config/connect-distributed.properties sink.json
```

it gets errored:

```
    [2022-09-21 14:02:32,328] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1663768952327 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:121)
    [2022-09-21 14:02:32,557] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:935)
    [2022-09-21 14:02:32,561] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 213ms, elapsed time since send: 213ms, request timeout: 3600000ms) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:341)
    [2022-09-21 14:02:32,665] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:935)
```

Also, have a doubt about where to write consumer details (in this case ADB ) like connection details, table name etc.I wrote sink connector properties file. but seems that is also not correct. will be helpful to know.

Comment: 1) Oracle cloud _probably_ doesn't use PLAINTEXT kafka connection, so you seem to be missing some auth /security settings 2) Connector properties need to be completely  **valid** JSON file, not some combination of different formats (`connect-distributed.sh` only accepts **one argument**)

Comment: I am having the same issue as well